# How to fix issue with KeyboardAwareScrollView?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4V94.jpg)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amOHf.png)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { UrlTile } from 'react-native-maps';
import tw from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';
import { Card } from 'react-native-shadow-cards';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

const MapScreen = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    let location = {
        latitude: 5.354846154402075,
        longitude: 100.30152659738222,
        latitudeDelta: 0.001,
        longitudeDelta: 0.002
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white h-full`}>

            <View style={tw`h-2/3`}>
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    mapType='standard'
                    region={location}>
                    <UrlTile
                        urlTemplate='https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=2fFGEOiBVDCSMRNfaU70'
                        shouldReplaceMapContent={true}>
                    </UrlTile>
                </MapView>
            </View>

            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
                bounces={false}
                enableOnAndroid={true}
                scrollEnabled={true}
                enableAutomaticScroll={true}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
                    <Card style={styles.cardView}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}>From</Text>
                        <View style={styles.inputBox}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={{ paddingVertical: 0, paddingLeft: 10 }}
                                placeholder='Current Location'
                                keyboardType='current-location'>
                            </TextInput>
                        </View>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}>To</Text>
                        <View style={styles.inputBox}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={{ paddingVertical: 0, paddingLeft: 10 }}
                                placeholder='Destination'
                                keyboardType='destination'>
                            </TextInput>
                        </View>

                        <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ShowResultScreen')}
                                style={styles.button}>
                                <Text
                                    style={{
                                        textAlign: 'center',
                                        fontWeight: '700',
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        color: '#fff'
                                    }}>
                                    Search
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </Card>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

        </SafeAreaView>
    );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    map: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },
    cardContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 25,
        shadowOpacity: 0.8
    },
    cardView: {
        width: '97%',
        height: '95%',
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingTop: 3
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: '#5AA9E6',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginTop: 15,
        marginRight: 10
    },
    inputBox: {
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: '97%',
        height: '15%',
        backgroundColor: '#F5F3F4',
        marginTop: 10
    }
});

export default MapScreen;
```

I want to make the input section below is scrollable and not covered by the keyboard when the keyboard is pop up so that the Search button can be pressed after typing the required input.

*Update: I have used KeyboardAwareScrollView instead of using KeyboardAvoidingView and ScrollView. However, the result is like the Screenshot2.*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the package react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.

Comment: still the same issue after i replace ScrollView and KeyboardAvoidingView with KeyboardAwareScrollView.

Comment: I did not check the same with your code, but you will find in the docs of the same package that you can add some offsets to make really everything visible. AND please get rid of KeyboardAvoidingView and replace the Scoll view with the same.

Comment: Can you help me to check? I have added KeyboardAwareScrollView, however the thing doesn't work.

Comment: enableOnAndroid={true} extraScrollHeight={-50} please try with something like this if you did not already

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import {useHeaderHeight} from '@react-navigation/elements';
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
....

<KeyboardAvoidingView
   style={{flexGrow: 1}}
   behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : undefined}
   keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? headerHeight + Constants.statusBarHeight : 0}>
   <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
    
    .... Put your code here ....
    
   </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```